# open several files into same buffer

Tags: vimscript, buffers, hidden-buffers

I have several file paths saved in a register. I would like to open them all into the same new buffer. (as if I ran `cat * files | vim -` from command line.

As this is part of a plugin, I would like to do this all with vim script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `:read` command reads a file into the current buffer; although it only works for one file. You'll need to add a new command which calls `:read` in a loop:

```
command! -nargs=+ -complete=file Read
        \  for f in [<f-args>]
        \|    exe ':$read ' f 
        \| endfor
```

You need the `$` range in read to tell it to append the file to the end of the buffer; by default the cursor stays in place, so the files will get intermixed.

You can also call `glob()` if you want to accept things such as `*.vim`; I added support for this in my little [globedit.vim](https://github.com/arp242/globedit.vim/) plugin.